# Она восприняла его поступок, как первый шаг к ненависти.

Tags: cинтаксис

*Она восприняла его поступок, **как первый шаг к ненависти**.*

*как первый шаг к ненависти* - сравнительный оборот, верно? А как сказать, чем он выражен?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Она восприняла его поступок как первый шаг к ненависти.-Здесь оборот с КАК не отделяется запятой, потому что его основное значение - отождествление: поступок  отождествляется с первым шагом к ненависти. Можно объяснить и как "в качестве"-поступок в качестве первого шага к ненависти. Выражен оборот сочетанием фразеологизма "первый шаг" (=начало) и сущ. с предлогом.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, Людмила! это тоже фразеологизм?!! наверно в наших языках по разному трактуют понятие "фразеологизм"...

Comment: фразеологизм здесь только "первый шаг", потому что приравнивается к  одному слову - начало.

Answer (score 3):

Она восприняла его поступок как первый шаг к ненависти.

Оборот со значением тождества, выражен словосочетанием.

Не очень ясно, почему его следует считать фразеологизмом.